# Why solver ECOS in cvxpy cannot solve this LP problem?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cvxpy

I am trying to solve the following LP using ECOS in CVXPY. But it tells me
'''
Solver 'ECOS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
'''
When I tried "verbose=True", it shows:

'''
Unreliable search direction detected, recovering best iterate (0) and stopping.

NUMERICAL PROBLEMS (reached feastol=1.7e+00, reltol=-nan(ind), abstol=3.9e+02).
Runtime: 0.663398 seconds.
'''
Here is my code:
'''

```
cons = np.array([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [  -1,   -0,   -0,   -0,   -0,   -0,   -0],\
 [-160,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [  40,   -1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [-160,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [  40,    0,   -1,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [-160,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0],\
 [  40,    0,    0,   -1,    0,    0,   0],\
 [-160,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0],\
 [  40,    0,    0,    0,   -1,    0,    0],\
 [-160,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0],\
 [  40,    0,    0,    0,    0,   -1,    0],\
 [-160,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1],\
 [  40,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,   -1],\
 [ -40,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [ -55,   -1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [ -40,   -1,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [ -55,    1,   -1,    0,    0,    0,    0],\
 [ -40,    0,   -1,    1,    0,    0,    0],\
 [ -55,    0,    1,   -1,    0,    0,    0],\
 [ -40,    0,    0,   -1,    1,    0,    0],\
 [ -55,    0,    0,    1,   -1,    0,    0],\
 [ -40,    0,    0,    0,   -1,    1,    0],\
 [ -55,    0,    0,    0,    1,   -1,    0],\
 [ -40,    0,    0,    0,    0,   -1,    1],\
 [ -55,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,   -1]])

const = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

x = cvx.Variable(7)

temp = [0,3,12,14,16,19]

buji = list(set(list(range(26)))-set(temp))

constraints = [cons[temp]@x==const[temp], cons[buji]@x<=const[buji]]

obj = cvx.Minimize(1)

prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)

prob.solve(verbose=True)

print(prob.status)
```

'''

What is wrong with this LP problem?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, although linear dependencies in constraints, like you have here, tend to cause numerical problems in solvers if not removed by you or by the solver. This is just a guess though. Both SCS and Mosek say infeasible with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try SCS or Mosek~